# Jenkins on Windows gets stuck on Fabric remote command when deploying Python app

Tags: python, windows, ssh, jenkins, fabric

I have this Jenkins build configuration for my Django application in "Execute Windows batch command" field:

```
// Code is downloaded using Git plugin 
virtualenv data/.venv
call data/.venv/Scripts/activate.bat
pip install -r requirements/local.txt

cd src/
python .\manage.py test

cd ..
fabric dev deploy // Build job get stuck here
```

All steps work OK except the last one. Jenkins gets stuck on first Fabric attempt to connect to remote server. In "Console output" is spinner keep spinning and I need to kill build manually.

When I run Fabric task manually from CLI, it works. I read about some problems with Jenkins+known_hosts, so I tried `env.reject_unknown_hosts = True` in fabfile to see if there is "Add to authorized keys" question.

Fabfile is pretty standard, nothing special:

```py
@task
def dev():
    env.user = "..."
    env.hosts = "..."
    env.key_filename = "..."
    nv.reject_unknown_hosts = True


@task
def deploy():
    local("python src/manage.py check") # <---- OK, output is in Jenkins

    run('git reset --hard') # <---- Jenkins will freeze
    run('git pull --no-edit origin master')

    # etc ....

    print("Done.")
```

Answer (score 0):

These requires a password, the process is probbaly stuck asking for user's password.

Add `--no-pty` to the command to make sure it's not blocking and reporting the error.
It is than solved based o your specific remote/ssh/tty setup.